# @Inject not working for AuthFilter in Guice + Jersey2

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm attempting to use Guice to inject dependencies into my custom AuthFilter which implements ContainerRequestFilter. 
My aim is to have an AuthenticationFilter that is applied to specific Resource. @Inject is working fine for the Resource classes but not for the Authfilter class.

Authetication Filter looks like

```
public class MyApiAuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Inject
    private InjectableResource injectableresource;
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) {
     //Filter Logic
   }
}
```

This is how I register the authfilter and guice-hk2 bridge

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public MyApplication(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
        register(MyApiAuthFilter.class);

        register(new ContainerLifecycleListener() {
            public void onStartup(Container container) {
                ServletContainer servletContainer = (ServletContainer)container;
                GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
                GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
                Injector injector = (Injector) servletContainer.getServletContext().getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
                guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
            }
            public void onReload(Container container) {

            }
            public void onShutdown(Container container) {
            }
        });

    }
```

InjectableResource is an implementation class for InjectableResourceInterface. I have annotated InjectableResourceInterface with @ImplementedBy annotation.

I am getting startup error. Error log:

```
WARN The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=InjectableResource,parent=MyApiAuthFilter,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1601756706)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
```

Any workaround so that @Inject also works for the AuthFilter?

Comment: It is unclear which class member you're annotated with @Inject. In most cases it should be constructor or field.

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: so is your field is `null` or you getting startup errors or something else? Also, please show how exactly you bingind the `InjectableResource` in the module class.

Comment: I am getting startup error.

Comment: Using `@ImplementedBy` not the best idea imo.. I'll suggest you to try with real module, like   in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53091143/4842099) answer

Comment: I am sure this will not make any difference. The variable InjectableResource works fine in the Resource class. I think my issue here is similar to [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642987/guice-jersey-2-containerrequest But I was not able to figure out a solution for this.